# libjpeg-turbo8-dev broken package dependencies (16.04)?

Tags: 16.04, dependencies, arm

I am getting this error when I try to install `libjpeg-turbo8-dev`. I am fairly new to Linux and I do not know how to resolve this issue.

This is the partial output when I run `sudo apt install libjpeg-turbo8-dev`.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjpeg-turbo8-dev : Depends: libjpeg-turbo8 (= 1.4.2-0ubuntu3) but 1.4.2-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is the `sudo apt-cache policy libjpeg-turbo8-dev` output.

```
libjpeg-turbo8-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.4.2-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
      1.4.2-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main arm64 Packages
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

[image: 1]

After running `sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get update`

[image: 2]

Comment: Welcome to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)!! what the output of `sudo apt-cache policy libjpeg-turbo8-dev`? and please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1094742/edit) your question with that output.

Comment: try to type `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-turbo8-dev=1.4.2-0ubuntu3`

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: try to run `sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get install libjpeg-turbo8-dev=1.4.2-0ubuntu3`

Comment: please provide me all the output errors of your commands?

Comment: i.imgur.com/8f83aIh.png

Comment: try to add your image on your question!!!

Comment: you have "The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required : ", try to run `sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get update` to fixing broken packages

Comment: After I ran `sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get update`, I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: the depends of [libjpeg-turbo8-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libjpeg-turbo8-dev) package available on arm64 architecture, not on amd64 or i382. where the architecture your have to get that package?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I am running on a Jetson TX2 which should be arm64?

Comment: to install it for amd64 architecture, run `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg-turbo8=1.4.2-0ubuntu3.1`

Comment: or install it for arm64 architecture, run `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg-turbo8=1.4.2-0ubuntu3`

Comment: Yes, `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg-turbo8=1.4.2-0ubuntu3` worked. Thanks!

Comment: is there an error output that appears?

Comment: No, it ran fine.

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: if my answered section can solved your issue, accepted it with a green check!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments

you have the `libjpeg-turbo8-dev` package on Arm64 architecture like at `apt-cache policy` appears

```
libjpeg-turbo8-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.4.2-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
      1.4.2-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main arm64 Packages
```

you get the errors :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjpeg-turbo8-dev : Depends: libjpeg-turbo8 (= 1.4.2-0ubuntu3) but 1.4.2-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Couse** you're not selected that package as Arm64 architecture. try to type

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg-turbo8=1.4.2-0ubuntu3
```

Hope this helps.